# Can't get coundown timer to work or display in my program

Tags: android, textview, countdowntimer, do-loops

I'm a newer programmer and this is my first project but I'm having a bit of trouble in making a proper loop with three timers that are supposed to run one after the other. I managed to get the objects to hold the values they are supposed to within the loop but for some reason, the timer isn't displaying in the text field like it should.

```
          startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("mTimer:", String.valueOf(mTimer));
            Log.i("mReps:", String.valueOf(mReps));
            Log.i("Flexion:", String.valueOf(flexionTimer));
            Log.i("Hold:", String.valueOf(holdTimer));
            Log.i("Extension:", String.valueOf(extensionTimer));

            for (int iter = 0; iter < mReps; iter++) {
                Log.i("Loop:", String.valueOf(iter));

                final Timer workingFlexionTimer = new Timer();
                workingFlexionTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    int counter = ((int) flexionTimer / 1000);
                    @Override
                    public void run () {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mPhase.setText("Flexion");
                                mCountDownTimer.setText("" + String.format(String.valueOf(counter + 1)));
                            }
                        });
                        if (counter-- == 0) {
                            workingFlexionTimer.cancel();
                        }
                    }
                }, 0, 1000);


                final Timer workingHoldTimer = new Timer();
                workingHoldTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    int counter = ((int) holdTimer / 1000);
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mPhase.setText("Hold!!!");
                                mCountDownTimer.setText("" + String.format(String.valueOf(counter + 1)));
                            }
                        });
                        if (counter-- == 0) {
                            workingHoldTimer.cancel();
                        }
                    }
                }, flexionTimer, 1000);

                final Timer workingExtensionTimer = new Timer();
                workingExtensionTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    int counter = ((int) extensionTimer / 1000);
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mPhase.setText("Extension");
                                mCountDownTimer.setText("" + String.format(String.valueOf(counter + 1)));
                            }
                        });
                        if (counter-- == 0) {
                            workingExtensionTimer.cancel();
                        }
                    }
                }, (flexionTimer + holdTimer), 1000);
            }
```

I'm kind of at a loss at this point and any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

For timers I always do:

```
    final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        int counter = 10;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText(""+counter);
                }
            });

            if (counter-- == 0){
                timer.cancel();
            }

        }
    }, 0, 1000);

timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        int counter = 10;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText(""+counter);
                }
            });

            if (counter-- == 0){
                timer.cancel();
            }

        }
    }, 10000, 1000);


timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        int counter = 10;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText(""+counter);
                }
            });

            if (counter-- == 0){
                timer.cancel();
            }

        }
    }, 20000, 1000);
```

For more info [check this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

In the link...

> public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)

The above code. Start the **run()** without delay.

```
long delay = 0;// in ms
long period = 1000;// in ms
```

So every 1000ms call the **run()** and counter--. When counter = 0 cancel.

If you want to run, the one after the other, put delay.

**UPDATE**

Now the first will run immediately, the second will wait 10000ms (10s) and will run, finaly the third will wait 20000ms (20s) and then run.

Comment: This is for 10 seconds, correct? The end result I'm hoping for is that flexion would go, then hold, then extension and that process would repeat itself until the i iterator was the same as mReps. I was thinking using this but making three and having one go after another in my do loop.

Comment: I tried implementing your method like this:                     new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        int counter = Integer.valueOf((int) (flexionTimer/1000));
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mPhase.setText("Flexion");
                            mCountDownTimer.setText("" + counter);
                            if (counter-- == 0) {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }, 0, 1000); and crashed the app.

Comment: Doing this:                 do {
                    final Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            int counter = (int) flexionTimer / 1000;
                            mCountDownTimer.setText("" + counter);
                            if (counter-- == 0) {
                                timer.cancel();
                            }
                        }
                    }, 0, 1k } while (iter <= mReps); got me the following error.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
                                                                            Process: com.heraldorapps.motiontimer, PID: 2622
                                                                            android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: @Dan You can't call a method on view from other thread. The run() method is running on new thread. "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." error says. I forgot that. Please see the new update. Sorry

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting it but where you made your code comment, and I'm just making sure I'm understanding this isn't some kind of pre-made method, is where I put the int counter = flexionTimer thing right?

Comment: This works, now I have to figure out how to make the other two go immediately afterward. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for accepting. See the update, for the more than one Timer.

Comment: Nice, it works well now. Do you mind giving another suggestion for my do loop? The timer displays but it does not repeat itself after one time.

Comment: for (int iter = 0; iter < mReps; iter++) {
                    Log.i("Loop:", String.valueOf(iter));

                    final Timer workingFlexionTimer = new Timer();
 

                    final Timer workingHoldTimer = new Timer();


                    final Timer workingExtensionTimer = new Timer();
                    
                } I can't put the full code but after the instantiation of the Timers, there is the full code for each Timer as it is in the example

Comment: Put your code in your question above. Not here at the comments. Full code, of all timers.

Comment: A timer is a new thread. In each loop, the new timers overwite the old timer immediately. Try : Thread.sleep(totalTimeOfAllTimersInMS); Put that code before the end of for loop.

Comment: It's saying that there will be an InterruptedException which I let the compiler auto fix and that caused the program to page/freeze.

Comment: The entire section of code is now underlined in red.

Comment: Ok, I made a mistake when making the new Thread. I thought I had to initialize it with a name. The code works but still doesn't loop though.

Answer (score 1):

Use handler

```
    private void Timer() {
        handler = new Handler();
        Run =new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() { //Do something after 10 sec
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Timer called!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Timer(); // Do again                
        }};
        handler.postDelayed(Run , 10000);  // 10 sec
    }
```

Comment: I'm curious as to where you would input this suggestion. As a method outside the onCreate method? In the MainActivity class? And where would I input the three values that I need to time? Thank you for the response!

Comment: In MainActivity as method . You can change method as you wish for example : private void Timer(int counter) { ... handler.postDelayed(Run , counter); }

Comment: And Toast would be changed to the TextView, correct?

Comment: It keeps saying that Handler is abstract and cannot be instantiated and that postDelayed needs a method.

Comment: use import android.os.Handler;  and fields on MainActivity   private Handler handler;
    private Runnable Run;

Answer (score 0):

The first timer **flexionCountDownTimer** was started in a loop, which means it will be started more than one time if **mReps** is greater than 1. This might leads to 2nd run of **flexionCountDownTimer** before the 1st run finished. Is this your expected behavior?

Comment: Essentially, flexionCountDownTimer would run, then holdCountDownTimer, then extensionCountDownTimer and then the process would repeat for however many mReps a user has given, which I have already figured out. Visually mReps(flexionCDT > holdCDT > extensionCDT)

Comment: @Dan Your code won't work as you expected. Suppose **flexionCountDownTimer** will count down 10 seconds. But because of **flexionCountDownTimer** is started in the loop. The 2nd start of **flexionCountDownTimer** will not wait until the 1st run of **flexionCountDownTimer** finished. Suppose **mReps** is 3, visually it will be (flexionCDT > flexionCDT > flexionCDT > holdCDT > extensionCDT)

Comment: Ok, I think I get it, I thought that putting the other methods in the onFinish of the previous CDT would cause them to run one after another.